# php script ends after 20 minutes, windows server php 5.3

Tags: php

I'm running a php script from the command line. I've set max_execution_time to 2400, 24000, and 0 to no effect. At 20 minutes the script ends.

I've also tried running it by passing exec time in the command line via -d sex_max_execution_time=#### - again, ends after 20 minutes.

I thought when running it in CLI mode it defaults to unlimited execution time.

Anyone have any ideas why this keeps ending after 20 minutes even when i specifically set it for a longer period?

This is on a windows 2012 server using php 5.3

nothing shows up in the php error log.

Comment: The script may be stopped due to memory limit, try to set a bigger limit : `set_time_limit (0) ;
   ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`

Comment: some servers may enforce a timeout, outside of the control of the PHP developer. This may be configured by the hosting provider to prevent runaway scripts. If that's the problem here, you may not be able to work around it. (however, enforced timeouts would normally be a lot less than 20 minutes, so mayby this isn't your problem).

Comment: sex_max_execution_time will not work, is this a typo in the command you issued  or in the SO question?

Comment: The one question I would ask is why do you need to have a PHP script running for 20 minutes? Is this something that actually needs to run for that long, or is it just very slow? Have you tried profiling it to see if you can make it run faster?

Comment: anigel - it was a typo, spudley - yes it really does need to run for more then 20 minutes. Utopik - already increased memory limit to 512 but i dont think that's the issue. it would be very strange indeed if the memory limit was reached at exactly 20 minutes every time. Plus I've been watching it run in task manager and it never goes above 10 megs or so. Spudley - i run the server :) So no issues of enforced limits by a 3rd party host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line into your PHP:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

That specifies the time limit for script execution is unlimited.

Comment: This function is just an alternative way to set `max_execution_time`, which the OP claims that didn't work.

Comment: We're going to try this. My understanding of how set_time_limit works is that it resets the limit each time you call it. So we're just going to call it in a loop and hopefully that'll reset the 20 minute clock. Although I'm doubtful since from what i've read, running from the command line should have an unlimited execution time, not to mention setting the limit above 20 minutes had no effect at all. So i'm doubtful this will work, but we're going to give it a try.

Comment: we set it to 600 and it seems to be working. I guess since we're calling this bit of code in a loop, it's resetting the counter. I still wish i knew why there was limit being enforced though since everything i've read seems to indicate running php from the command line should have no limit by default, not to mention it ignores any limit above 20 minutes when i explicitly set one.